# Falla el filtro where en la consulta

Tags: laravel

Tengo el siguiente código que funciona bien.

```
$visits = Visit::leftjoin('profiles', 'visits.user_id', '=', 'profiles.user_id')
                        ->selectRaw('visits.id as vid, profiles.name as uname, visits.first_name as vfn, visits.last_name as vln,
                gender, visits.cuit as vc, DATE_FORMAT(date_of_birth, "%d-%m-%Y") as birth, DATE_FORMAT(visits.created_at, "%d-%m-%Y") as date, TIME(visits.created_at) as hour')
                        ->orWhere('profiles.grandfather_id', $id)
                        ->orWhere('profiles.father_id', $id)
                        ->orWhere('profiles.user_id', $id)
                        ->paginate(50);

        return view('admin.dashboard.visits.admin-index', compact('visits'));
```

Pero al agregar esta sentencia, no la incluye en el filtro:

```
->where('visits.created_at', '>=', now()->subDays(15))
```

Queda así:

```
$visits = Visit::leftjoin('profiles', 'visits.user_id', '=', 'profiles.user_id')
                        ->selectRaw('visits.id as vid, profiles.name as uname, visits.first_name as vfn, visits.last_name as vln,
                gender, visits.cuit as vc, DATE_FORMAT(date_of_birth, "%d-%m-%Y") as birth, DATE_FORMAT(visits.created_at, "%d-%m-%Y") as date, TIME(visits.created_at) as hour')
                        ->where('visits.created_at', '>=', now()->subDays(15))
                        ->orWhere('profiles.grandfather_id', $id)
                        ->orWhere('profiles.father_id', $id)
                        ->orWhere('profiles.user_id', $id)
                        ->paginate(50);

        return view('admin.dashboard.visits.admin-index', compact('visits'));
```

Quitando estas tres y dejando la anterior funciona:

```
->orWhere('profiles.grandfather_id', $id)
->orWhere('profiles.father_id', $id)
->orWhere('profiles.user_id', $id)
```

Así:

```
$visits = Visit::leftjoin('profiles', 'visits.user_id', '=', 'profiles.user_id')
                        ->selectRaw('visits.id as vid, profiles.name as uname, visits.first_name as vfn, visits.last_name as vln,
                gender, visits.cuit as vc, DATE_FORMAT(date_of_birth, "%d-%m-%Y") as birth, DATE_FORMAT(visits.created_at, "%d-%m-%Y") as date, TIME(visits.created_at) as hour')
                        ->where('visits.created_at', '>=', now()->subDays(15))
                        ->paginate(50);

        return view('admin.dashboard.visits.admin-index', compact('visits'));
```

Consulta Sql();

```
select visits.id as vid, profiles.name as uname, visits.first_name as vfn, visits.last_name as vln, gender, visits.cuit as vc, DATE_FORMAT(date_of_birth, "%d-%m-%Y") as birth, DATE_FORMAT(visits.created_at, "%d-%m-%Y") as date, TIME(visits.created_at) as hour from `visits` left join `profiles` on `visits`.`user_id` = `profiles`.`user_id` where `visits`.`created_at` >= ? or `profiles`.`grandfather_id` = ? or `profiles`.`father_id` = ? or `profiles`.`user_id` = ?
```

Comment: Al final de la consulta en lugar de paginate usa `toSql()` y agrega a tu pregunta que consulta se esta formando

Comment: Agregada a la pregunta, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Basado en la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) se puede estar debiendo a un problema agrupando las condiciones a cumplir por los múltiples `where` que existen en tu consulta.

La solución propuesta es usar el método `orWhere` una función la cual por dentro retornará los múltiples `where` opcionales.

Además de eso podemos mover el `->where('visits.created_at', '>=', now()->subDays(15))` antes de la solución propuesta arriba, ya que ese no parece ser opcional a cumplirse.

Quendando así:

```
$visits = Visit::leftjoin('profiles', 'visits.user_id', '=', 'profiles.user_id')
                ->selectRaw('visits.id as vid, 
                            profiles.name as uname, 
                            visits.first_name as vfn, 
                            visits.last_name as vln,
                            gender, 
                            visits.cuit as vc, 
                            DATE_FORMAT(date_of_birth, "%d-%m-%Y") as birth, 
                            DATE_FORMAT(visits.created_at, "%d-%m-%Y") as date, TIME(visits.created_at) as hour')
                ->where('visits.created_at', '>=', now()->subDays(15))
                ->orWhere(function ($query) use($id){
                    return $query->orWhere('profiles.grandfather_id', $id)
                                ->orWhere('profiles.father_id', $id)
                                ->orWhere('profiles.user_id', $id);
                })->paginate(50);
```

Comment: No, igualmente no lo filtra :(

Comment: Transforma como te indiqué en tu pregunta la consulta a SQL, copia y pega en tu interfaz que uses para acceder a MySQL y prueba si ahi trae o no el resultado esperado

Comment: Lo hago a través de Phpmyadmin pero me da error, por el modelo

Comment: Que error te da la consultA?

Comment: Diría que hay que cambiar el primer `->orWhere` por un `andWhere`, o como se llame el método que genere un `and` y no un `or`.

Comment: @jachguate sería simplemente `where` lo cual generaría un `AND` me pareció que después del primer where iba un or por eso lo puse así, de todos modos ayudaría el OP indique que error da pues la consulta así máximo tal vez no filtre correcto pero no un error como dice

Comment: Ya logré la consulta, era un error de mi parte, me lista todos los resultados igual que el la Web

Comment: Prueba el cambio que surge del comentario de jachguate

Comment: No, no me han servido, eliminé la respuesta porque iba a probar algo más pero tampoco funcionó